# Elasticsearch - Autocomplete return word/term/token suggestions instead of whole documents

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, lucene

I am trying to implement a simple auto completion for query terms.
There are many different approaches but most of them do return documents instead of terms
- or the authors simply stopped explaining from that point and i am  not able to adapt.

A user is typing in a query - e.g. *phil*
What i want is to **provide a list of term completion suggestions** like *philipp, philius, philadelphia, ...*

I am able to get document matches via (edge)ngrams, phrase_prefix and so on but i am am stuck at retrieving matching terms (completion suggestions).

Can someone give me a hint?

I have documents like this {"title":"...", "description":"...", "content":"..."}
All fields have larger string values but especially the field content contains fulltext content.

I do not want to suggest the whole title of a document containing e.g. Philadelphia. Just the word "Philadelphia".

Comment: Hi, just to be certain; Did you try https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html ?

Comment: I did try completion suggester. But it only returns predefined output (or uses input as output). But suggests are way too long as i am working with fulltext documents. ... or am i missing something? I need to get term suggestions only.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for something like that, myself.

In SOLR it was relatively simple to configure (although a pain to build and keep up-to-date) using solr.SpellCheckComponent. Somehow the same underlying Lucene functionality is used differently between SOLR and ElasticSearch, and in ElasticSearch it is geared towards finding whole documents (or whole field values, if you will) or so it seems...

Despite the profusion of "elasticsearch autocomplete" articles, none appears to deal with this particular issue. Like it doesn't exist. Maybe their use case is different and ElasticSearch works for them just fine, who knows?

At this point I think that preparing the exact field values to use with ElasticSearch autocomplete (yes, that's the *input field values*, not *analyzer tokens*) maybe the only way to solve the problem. Which is terrible, because the performance is going to be very low.

Comment: As your answer doesn't actually answer the question it would be better served as a comment to the post rather than an answer. Just food for thought for your comments/answers going forward.

Comment: My rep is below the threshold allowing to post comments.

Comment: For me preparing the exact autocomplete values (output values) is not an option as i am working with huge document body of which each word might become an autocomplete suggestion. Tokenizing the autocomplete field seems not to work :-(

Comment: As a last-ditch resort I did try preparing the exact autocomplete values. I had to create a separate document type for that, too. Although the index was built (with a staggering number of documents, I must add), the completion suggester still did not work as expected. That was as far as I was willing to go with making ElasticSearch work. If you have a choice, give SOLR a try.

Comment: I worked with solr in our previous project. We just switched to elasticsearch because of its (in my opinion) easier clustering and more freedom regarding document structure. Haven't tried recent solr releases though.

Answer (score 0):

Try [term suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#term-suggester):

> The term suggester suggests terms based on edit distance. The provided
>   suggest text is analyzed before terms are suggested. The suggested
>   terms are provided per analyzed suggest text token. The term suggester
>   doesn’t take the query into account that is part of request.